# Change magento2 cms page layout

Tags: magento2, layout, cms, home

I am using 2 column left in home page. It is a cms page. In responsive i need to load as

```
<div class="sidebar sidebar-main"></div>
<div class="column main"></div>
```

Comment: this class by default loaded.What you want?

Comment: By default it is loaded as <div class="column main"></div> <div class="sidebar sidebar-main"></div> this i  need as given in my question

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order of these divs by overriding the following file:

> /vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml

I have managed to change the order by modifying the code of above file. Check the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>
    <referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-main" before="main">
            <container name="sidebar.main" as="sidebar_main" label="Sidebar Main"/>
        </container>
        <container name="div.sidebar.additional" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar sidebar-additional" after="div.sidebar.main">
            <container name="sidebar.additional" as="sidebar_additional" label="Sidebar Additional"/>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

This will take effect on mobile and desktop both views. Afterwards you can change the css according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but thought I'd add my approach for anyone that might come across the same issue.

If I understood the question correctly, you would like to swap the order of the divs around for responsive design (mobile for example). This could be done with CSS Flex-box

Starting HTML:

```
<div class="surrounding-div">
   <div class="column main"></div>
   <div class="sidebar sidebar-main"></div>
</div>
```

Add the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .surrounding-div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
     }

   .sidebar-main {
     order: 0; // places this div as the first child of the flex parent
   }
}
```

Mobile would now render as:

```
<div class="surrounding-div">
   <div class="column main"></div>
   <div class="sidebar sidebar-main"></div>
</div>
```